# Extending a React Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-forwardref

I am running v5 of Styled Components and am having some issues extending a styled component. I will show the code below.

I have a Heading component which returns a React.FC containing a StyledHeading. Then, in a different file, I am trying to extend Heading. However, when doing this, the Heading component doesn't even seem to run. I put a console log in the component and it doesn't render.

**Heading**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

import { font, fontSize, color, breakpoint } from 'theme';

interface Props {
  as: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6';
  appearAs?: 'h1' | 'h1-jumbo' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6';
  align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
  className?: string;
}

const Heading: React.FC<Props> = ({ as, appearAs = as, align = 'left', className, children }) => {
  const jumbo = appearAs === 'h1-jumbo';

  console.log('in heading'); // Runs when not extending, doesn't run when extending

  return (
    <StyledHeading as={as} appearAs={appearAs} align={align} jumbo={jumbo} className={className}>
      {children}
    </StyledHeading>
  );
};

const H1Styles = css<Props & { jumbo?: boolean }>`
  font-size: ${({ jumbo }) => (jumbo ? fontSize('xl') : fontSize('lg'))};
  text-align: ${({ jumbo, align }) => (jumbo ? 'center' : align)};

  @media (max-width: ${breakpoint('sm')}) {
    font-size: ${({ jumbo }) => jumbo && fontSize('lg')};
  }
`;

const StyledHeading = styled.div<Props & { jumbo?: boolean }>`
  font-family: ${font('bold')};
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: ${({ align }) => align};
  white-space: pre-wrap;

  ${({ appearAs }) => appearAs === 'h1' && H1Styles}
  ${({ appearAs }) => appearAs === 'h1-jumbo' && H1Styles}
`;

export default Heading;
```

**Usage**

```
// Renders an H2 but doesn't process appearAs or run console log
<StyledHeading as="h2" appearAs="h1-jumbo">TEST</StyledHeading>

// Renders an H2, appearAs works, and console log runs
<Heading as="h2" appearAs="h1-jumbo>TEST>/Heading>

const StyledHeading = styled(Heading)`margin-bottom: 1000px;`;
```

Any advice would be tremendous because I feel at a wall currently. Thank you!

Comment: Can you recreate in codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj, just for notice I don't think you can pass props to `css` blocks, therefore this code might not work.

Comment: No need all TS types to reproduce the problem, try keeping it simple

Comment: If that's your actual usage, `StyledHeading` is used before definition. And TypeScript should be telling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That´s because your StyledHeading is wrapping another component and with that you need to use `forwardedAs` instead of `as`, like:

```js
<StyledHeading forwardedAs="h2" appearAs="h1-jumbo">
   TEST
</StyledHeading>

<Heading as="h2" appearAs="h1-jumbo">
   TEST
</Heading>
```

And for the above code works, you need to do some changes on `Props` interface as well as in the `Heading` component:

```
export interface Props {
  as?: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
  forwardedAs?: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
  appearAs?: "h1" | "h1-jumbo" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
  align?: "left" | "center" | "right";
  className?: string;
}

const Heading: React.FC<Props> = ({
  as,
  forwardedAs,
  appearAs = as || forwardedAs,
  align = "left",
  className,
  children,
}) => {
  const jumbo = appearAs === "h1-jumbo";

  console.log("in heading"); // Runs when not extending, doesn't run when extending

  return (
    <StyledHeading
      as={as}
      forwardedAs={forwardedAs}
      appearAs={appearAs}
      align={align}
      jumbo={jumbo}
      className={className}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledHeading>
  );
};
```

*As you can see, i set `as` and `forwardedAs` as optional property (As I do´t know how the component should behave, it's just an example).

Also, you can check this [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-component-fowardas-263o6?file=/src/App.tsx) that i did (If you click to update the url sample, you will see logging the component twice).

And finally, you can read more about this [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#forwardedas-prop).

Comment: Dude, you're so clutch. `forwardedAs` is exactly the piece I was missing. Thank you!